# Changing column names for an existing table

Tags: matlab, rename, default-value, variable-names, matlab-table

I have the following table in MATLAB:

```
A= 

    86   84
    45   65
     2   42
    44   29
```

MATLAB automatically returns for this table the column names `A1` and `A2`, with `A` being the set name of the table, for the two columns.

How can I manually change the names of each column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That can be easily accomplished using the `VariableNames` parameter of the [array2table function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html) (the same is valid for the [cell2table function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2table.html) too), as follows:

```
A = [
  86   84
  45   65
   2   42
  44   29
];

T = array2table(A,'VariableNames',{'X' 'Y'})
```

The output table is:

```
T =

    X     Y 
    __    __

    86    84
    45    65
     2    42
    44    29
```

For an already existing table, you can use the same property on the instance itself in order to change its column names:

```
A = [
  86   84
  45   65
   2   42
  44   29
];

T = array2table(A,'VariableNames',{'X' 'Y'})
T.Properties.VariableNames = {'U' 'V'};
T
```

Take a look at the outputs:

```
T =

    X     Y 
    __    __

    86    84
    45    65
     2    42
    44    29



T =

    U     V 
    __    __

    86    84
    45    65
     2    42
    44    29
```